# member access within misaligned address

Tags: stl, queue, runtime-error, c++14, undefined-behavior

question link : https://leetcode.com/problems/cousins-in-binary-tree

my code :

```
 /**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * struct TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode *left;
 *     TreeNode *right;
 *     TreeNode() : val(0), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
 *     TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
 *     TreeNode(int x, TreeNode *left, TreeNode *right) : val(x), left(left), right(right) {}
 * };
 */

class Solution {
public:

bool isCousins(TreeNode* root, int x, int y) {

    //breath first search will be better in this approach
    queue<  pair< TreeNode * , TreeNode *>   > a;
    queue<  pair< TreeNode * , TreeNode *>   > b; // first children..then parent
    a.push({root,NULL});//root-> parent = NULL
    bool check = false;
    auto it = a.front();
    auto it2 = a.front();
    while(a.size() !=0 || b.size() !=0){
        if(a.size() == 0 && b.size() != 0)
            a.swap(b);
        //if(b.size() == 0)
        //    b.push({NULL,NULL});
        it = a.front();
        if(it.first->left != NULL)
            b.push({it.first->left,it.first});
        if(it.first->right != NULL)
            b.push({it.first->right,it.first});
        if( it.first != NULL && (it.first->val == x || it.first->val == y)){
            //we need to find both in this level
            //if not found return false;
            while(a.size() != 0){
                a.pop();
                it2 = a.front();
//this is the line 40
//here....
                    if(it2.first != NULL && (((it2.first)->val == x) || ((it2.first)->val == y))){//all nodes are unique in value
                        if(it2.second == it.second)
                            return false;//same parent ..so not cousin
                        return true;//cousim
                    }    
                }
                //only one of them is found at present depth
                return false;
            }
            if(a.size() !=0)
                a.pop();
        }
        //both not found
        return false;
    }
};
```

> runtime error : Line 40: Char 60: runtime error: member access within misaligned address 0xbebebebebebebebe for type 'TreeNode', which requires 8 byte alignment (solution.cpp)
>   0xbebebebebebebebe: note: pointer points here
>   
>   SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior prog_joined.cpp:49:60

Comment: What difficulties did you face while debugging your code?

Comment: `if( it.first != NULL && ... ` It's a bit too late to check `it.first` for `NULL` **after** you've already dereferenced it a bunch of times.

Comment: `while(a.size() != 0){ a.pop(); it2 = a.front();`  If `a` has just one element, `a.pop()` will leave it empty, and then `a.front()` exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: @igor after a.pop() , while condition will be checked, is either of a and b is not empty, it will enter. Now if entered only because b was not empty but a was empty, then swap, now a is not empty and b is empty.

Comment: My intention was a will stores nodes at a level and b will store next level, when we have traversed all of a, then we move onto next level, if that also is empty.  It implies we have  completely traversed the tree.

Comment: Now when we check-- if (it.first ! = null) then it was just precautionary,  because we only insert in b (which is afterwards swaped with a) when the value is not null.

Comment: @ardent , actually I didn't understood the error, I tried googling, didn't helped much. I dry run the code, but couldn't notice the missing mistake.

Comment: `a` is not empty **before** the `a.pop()` call, but it may become empty after. Yet you go ahead and retrieve its element, which may not exist. Did you perhaps mean to read the element first, and `pop` second?

Comment: thanks @igor...understood what you wanted to say